# Logging custom structure using WPP

Tags: c++, windows, logging, windows-wpp

I'm trying to use WPP to log my own struct.
struct is:

```
struct A
{
int a;
int b;
}
```

I added localwpp.ini file to configuration and defined:

```
DEFINE_CPLX_TYPE(MYSTRUCTA, WPP_LOGWMYSTRUCTA, MYSTRUCTA, ItemLong,"d", x, 0, 1);
```

then i defined new macro in log.h:

```
#define WPP_LOGWMYSTRUCTA(x) WPP_LOGTYPEVAL(A, x)
```

And in my source code:

```
A x;
LOG(INFO, "%!MYSTRUCTA!", x);
```

Above is just a template. I was trying a lot of versions of that

My gould would be:

```
DEFINE_CPLX_TYPE(MYSTRUCTA, WPP_LOGWMYSTRUCTA, MYSTRUCTA, ItemListLong,"a:%d b:%d", x, 0, 2);
```

But then i can see in collected logs some random numbers. differs by 14.
In TMF file i can see that generated function will receive just one argument:

```
    L"{", \
    L"x, ItemListLong -- 10" , \
    L"}")
```

How can I log custom struct in my custom way using WPP? is ItemListLong proper typy for such a solution?
i checked also [defaultwpp.ini](https://github.com/antoxar/WPPTracingSample/blob/master/sample/WppTracing/WppConfig/Rev1/defaultwpp.ini) file. I can see there a lot of DEFINE_FLAVOR. What does it mean? I could't fine defeinition.

I tried with various types of args. I tried also somehow combine macro like
DEFINE_CPLX_TYPE(MYSTRUCTA, WPP_LOGWMYSTRUCTA, MYSTRUCTA, ItemListLong,"d!/%11!d", x, 0, 2);
basing on output tmf file to be aligned with expected pattern:

```
    L" 173 \"%0 %10!d!/%11!d!\" //   FLAGS=TRACE_FLAG_GENERAL LEVEL=INFO" \
```

But then second parameter is 0.

Comment: I also checked sth like that:
void MyCustomFormatFunction(CHAR* pBuffer, SIZE_T bufferSize, const A* pData)
{
 RtlStringCbPrintfA(
  pBuffer,
  bufferSize,
  "data: %d, %d",
  pData->a,
  pData->b);
}
DEFINE_CPLX_TYPE(A, WPP_LOGA, A, MyCustomFormatFunction, "s", _HEX_, 0, 1);

Comment: I also was trying to customize *.tpl files. I found there macros like that:

`FORALL Msg IN Messages WHERE MsgIsPrivate`
#ifdef WPP_PUBLIC_`Msg.FlagValue`
#define WPP_PUBLIC_ANNOT_`Msg.Name`
#endif
`ENDFOR`
`FORALL Msg IN Messages WHERE MsgIsPublic`
#define WPP_PUBLIC_ANNOT_`Msg.Name`
`ENDFOR`
#ifdef WPP_EMIT_FUNC_NAME
#define WPP_FUNC_NAME L" FUNC=" _WPPW(__FUNCTION__)
#else // WPP_EMIT_FUNC_NAME
#define WPP_FUNC_NAME
#endif // WPP_EMIT_FUNC_NAME
`FORALL Msg IN Messages`

Is there any GUIDE how Messages is defined and how to change it? Or how use this language?